# Loading grid children takes too long xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I'm developing an app in xamarin forms and in my portable classes there is a page that have a grid that I want to load with 90 children that all have several Images in them the View is called NumberBlock but it is taking 3-4 seconds to load the page and that is causing lag when running it on android phones(didn't try on others):

this is the NumberBlock view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="NumbersRaceXamarin.NumberBlock">
  <ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="90" WidthRequest="44" Spacing="5">
      <Image x:Name="pin" Source="push_pin.png" HeightRequest="21" WidthRequest="21" ></Image>
      <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" >
        <BoxView x:Name="selectedRect" HeightRequest="42" WidthRequest="42" Color="Blue" Opacity="0"/>
        <Label x:Name="numberTB" Text="" IsVisible="false"/>
        <Image  Source="block.png" HeightRequest="42" WidthRequest="42" ></Image>
        <Image x:Name="digit"   HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height , Factor=0.03,Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width , Factor=0.03,Constant=0}"></Image>
      </RelativeLayout>
      <Image x:Name="link" Source="linkicon_01.png" HeightRequest="14" WidthRequest="31" Opacity="0"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

this is how I load create the grid:

```
    public void refresh(Player pl)
    {
            LevelsGrid.Children.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < LevelManager.levels.Count; i++)
            {
                int kind = 2;
                if (i > pl.completedLevels.Count)
                {
                    kind = 0;
                }
                else if (i == pl.completedLevels.Count)
                {
                    kind = 1;
                }

                levelBlock bt = new levelBlock(kind, LevelManager.levels[i].levelName.Remove(0, 5));
                bt.HeightRequest = 40;
                bt.WidthRequest = 40;
                var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();

                tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += levelClick;
                bt.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
                LevelsGrid.Children.Add(bt, i % 8, i / 8);
            }
        coinsOwnedTB.Text = pl.coins + "";
        scoreTB.Text = pl.score + "";
    }
```

and this is how I run the refresh method:

```
    private async void runRef()
    {
      await  BeginInvokeOnMainThreadAsync(refresh);
    }
   public Task BeginInvokeOnMainThreadAsync(Action<Player> action)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
           {
               try
               {
                   action(cur);
                   tcs.SetResult(null);
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   tcs.SetException(ex);
               }
           });
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

My questions are:

1) Is there anyway more efficient to do what i'm doing that would make the process faster (running in the background somehow maybe!?)

2)if there isn't a way to make it faster is there a way to make the page appear and then the grid loads gradually?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using a `Grid`, you should really look at using a `ListView` with a caching option of `RecycleElement`, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried this and along with the BeginInvokeOnMainThread it did improve the performance but still I struggle to shape it like a grid, it is not an ideal control to show items in grid layout unless I'm missing something

Comment: @FadiBanna
Take a look at it:
https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView

Comment: @YuraBabiy thanks:) I did stumble across this  but I ended up solving my problem with a customRenderer built in android with a gridview I will post my solution soon.